# How do i specify a Class type argument with flow?

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I've a function which receives a class as a parameter :

`myFunction = (Klass) => new Klass();`

How do i specifiy `Klass` parameter with flow ?

If i use `Klass:SomeClass`, flow seems to be ok with that. But i was expecting this to give me an error since i thought `:SomeClass` would indicate "an instance of SomeClass", which is not the case in my example (i'm passing the class itself)

What is the correct notation for this example ?

**Edit:**

As Aleksey pointed out in the comment, we can use the Class utility :
`myFunction = (Klass:Class<SomeClass>) => new Klass();`

Comment: ClassA:ClassB = Inheritance?

Comment: You can use `Class` utility: `const myFunction = (c: Class<Klass>) => new c();`. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's it thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To represent class type (constructor function) of an instance type you can use [Class](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-class) utility:

```
class SomeClass {}

const myFunction = (c: Class<SomeClass>) => new c();
```